# Collapsed navbar background color change

Tags: css, responsive

There's a collapsed navbar on this  [website](https://wizard4socialmedia.com/)

The background color of the tabs is `white`, and I want to change it. I tried this code in CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-collapse
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

And it sort of works, it adds red lines under each tab, but it does not change the background color.
You can see what it does if you visit the site on mobile and click the navbar to collapse it.

I'm trying to change this only for MOBILE.

I'm sure there's an easy solution to this, but I can't figure it out.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because your grey background is set on anchors and not on NAV it self

if you do this:

```
.header ul.nav li a { 
  background: red;
}
```

it will work..

I just checked again and you have background added to 3 elements you have red on your outer wrapper, you have white added to list element and grey on your anchors

Comment: Thanks for answering. That sort of works, but not all the way. I implemented it and it only works on the the 1st dropdown tab, and only when I'm on the homepage.

Comment: @Overloard take out `.current-page` it will add it to all anchors on all pages

Comment: That's awesome. I tinkered with it a little and made it look sweet. I just have one small issue. When on the homepage and you collapse the menu, the "HOME" tab refuses to apply the CSS. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: you can add !important flag behind the color red such as `background: red !important` this will force the override of any other color applied

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your html there is inline style either remove that or change there the color or if you wanted that to change through css use following code:

```
.nav-collapse ul li { backgroud-color: red !important; }
```

[Inline style Refrence Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOzbe.png)